# EnsureCoreWebView2Async "invalid window handle" exception in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, webview2

when attempting to replace an AxWebBrowserwith WebView2 in an old winform form i get an
***"invalid window handle 0x80070578" exception.***

at first it was due to an older version of Edge but after dating to Canary it was working fine in a standalone project.

```
async void InitializeAsync()
{
    await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null); //this throws an exception
}
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a day of trying anything i could think of i noticed that the winform did not have a separate file for the designer. this got me thinking that maybe this is a compatibility thing (original form was created ~2015) so i attempted to recreate the winform in VS 2019.

**recreating the form worked as expected. it runs smoothly now.**
also worth noting  that the older form had this line

```
this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual;
```